# Parse 2d arrays in an optimal way

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array, hash

I need to parse the following hash of 2d arrays, where the first array has the keys and the rest of the arrays has the values.

```
input = {
  "result": [
    [
      "id",
      "name",
      "address"
    ],
    [
      "1",
      "Vishnu",
      "abc"
    ],
    [
      "2",
      "Arun",
      "def"
    ],
    [
      "3",
      "Arjun",
      "ghi"
    ]
  ]
}
```

This is the result I came up with.

```
input[:result].drop(1).collect{|arr| Hash[input[:result].first.zip arr]}
```

Here I'm iterating through the `result` array ignoring its first sub array (the one that contains keys) then `zip` the key array and value array to make a hash afterwards I collect the hash to another array.

The above solution gives me what I want which is a hash

```
[{"id"=>"1", "name"=>"Vishnu", "address"=>"abc"}, {"id"=>"2", "name"=>"Arun", "address"=>"def"}, {"id"=>"3", "name"=>"Arjun", "address"=>"ghi"}]
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zip` is the correct tool here, so your code is fine.

I'd use Ruby's [array decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) feature to extract keys and values, and `to_h` instead of `Hash[]`:

```
keys, *values = input[:result]
values.map { |v| keys.zip(v).to_h }
```

Or, if you prefer a "one-liner": (harder to understand IMO)

```
input[:result].yield_self { |k, *vs| vs.map { |v| k.zip(v).to_h } }
```

Comment: Array#yield_self way was excellent. Also, if you don't mind, can you explain how your first method is better?

Comment: If you're using Ruby 2.6.0 or higher you can use [`#then`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Object.html#method-i-then) instead of [`#yield_self`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Object.html#method-i-yield_self) which is shorter and is more understandable imo.

Comment: @vishnuprasanth both snippets are equivalent, I just find the first one easier to grasp.

Comment: In case it's not clear, @3limin4t0r's is saying that `Object#then` was introduced as an alias of `Object#yield_self` in v2.6.